# Bash check if mysql command failed

Tags: mysql, bash

I have the following bash script:

```
MYSQL="which mysql"
SQL="CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS TEST;"

read -p -s "Enter mySQL password:" DBPASS

$MYSQL -root -p$DBPASS -e "$SQL"
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; 
then
   echo "Failed."
else
   echo "Done."
fi
```

Even if I type wrong password the script says `"Done."`, as it can´t detect the mysql command error...

I need to be able to correctly show the `"Error."` message when someone types a wrong password.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps using `expect` - http://expect.sourceforge.net/ - would be a better bet

Comment: Replace `MYSQL="which mysql"` by `MYSQL="$(which mysql)"`.

Comment: `$(which mysql)`did not solved the problem...

Comment: It is the first of two bugs.

Comment: if "which mysql" found mysql so it is not necessary to do it. mysql also search in the $PATH and if you want to use you put it in backticks **MYSQL=`which mysql`** and the MySQL username must after -u. so -uroot

Comment: There's no need for the `read` command; `mysql` will prompt you for a password itself if you omit the argument to `-p`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$? == 0 means the command run successfully.

try this:

```
MYSQL="which mysql"
SQL="CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS TEST;"

read -p -s "Enter mySQL password:" DBPASS

$MYSQL -root -p$DBPASS -e "$SQL"
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; 
then
   echo "Done."
else
   echo "Failed."
fi
```

Comment: use:
`export phppath=$(which php)
echo $phppath` and add a newline before the `echo`